# Setting up a server for iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, tomcat, servlets, server

I am creating an app in Android which will also be made in iOS after it's ready.

I have successfully implemented a Tomcat serverlet in Eclipse between the device and the server.

Now both these platforms use Java. This isn't the case with iOS, which I am aware that you can't program with Java, but what about the serverlet? Can I even use Tomcat?

Some guidance will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use **ApacheTomcat**.

**Tomcat** is only the part of technology to *host* your **Servlet**.

This has nothing to do with the mobile apps that you are planning to build, since these are completely different components.

As I see it, your whole project will require to be implemented with three different technical components:

1. Your *backend*: This is your **Java Servlet**. It needs to run in a **Servlet Container**, which is indeed your **Apache Tomcat** setup
2. An **Android** app: Written in Java, talking to your *backend* via HTTP
3. An **iOS** app: Written in Swift/Objective-C, talking to your *backend* via HTTP

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not familiar with the "Servlet Container" you mentioned. Since my servlet is working, do I need to add anything else?

Comment: well, if your Servlet is running it means you have have your severlet container already in place. so, no, you don't have to add anything else :)